# JavaFX Execute operation every X ms while Window is open

Tags: user-interface, asynchronous, javafx

For my application I designed a simple log-window controlled by `ShopLogController.java`.

[image: log window]

This window takes the log information from the `ShopLog` (not to be confused with `ShopLogController`) class and displays it. However, the `ShopLog` itself is possibly modified by every Object in existance. So a way to check if the content changed is needed, in order to keep the contents of the log-window consistent with the text-log inside the `ShopLog` class.

The options I explored to far:

- Implement a public `update()` function in `ShopLogController` that is called whenever the log changes. 
  This works fine, but IMO violates the strict seperation of GUI/logic/persistence layers, as the logic layer explicitly calls the GUI in order to prompt it to update. 
  (Should you believe that this is not a violation of the layer-seperation, please explain why)
- Implement some kind of updater object that runs in its own thread and calls `update()` from above every X miliseconds. Not allowed by JavaFX as this produces a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-#`
- Start a thread inside the corresponding controller. This also works fine*ish*. The only problem is that the update would be sitting in an `while(true)` loop that never quits. A workable `on-close` method would be required to terminate this loop. I am not aware of such a solution for single windows, rather than whole applications. (See `stop()` )

How can I make my log (and other) window(s) update without explicitly prompting it to do so from outside; while still making the controller terminate on closing its window only?

As requested the code of the relevant objects:

[image: shopLogController]

[image: shopLog]

The structure is as basic as it gets here. There's a `String` in `ShopLog`, and when it changes I would like the `update()` in `ShopLogController` to be called. I would also like to avoid explicitly calling any controller functions from ShopLog, as it cannot be guaranteed that one exists (e.g. the log window was not opened yet).

PS: This is not really about finding `any` workable solution, but about finding an elegant one.

Comment: It looks like the log is displayed in a text area. Why not just add a listener to the text area's `textProperty()`? Or maybe I do not really understand the question...?

Comment: I'm not sure if I conveyed my problem correctly:

There is a ShopLog class which holds a String; representing the literal information of the log.

The shopLogController only handles whatever the GUI window does.

The change happens in the String first, and I would like the TextArea in the controller to update

Comment: OK, so use a `StringProperty` instead of a `String` and register a listener with it. Maybe you can post some code to explain what the problem is.

Comment: Since the documentation demands strict seperation of GUI and logic (e.g. during grading the GUI part will be replaced with a script running test inputs) I am very reluctant to use any JavaFX objects within the logic classes, especially when I'm going to register actual GUI elements to them (I can already see the nullpoiners).

Comment: I don't think using a `StringProperty` violates the separation of view and model: `StringProperty` has no UI associated with it and it specifically designed for use in a model representation. If you want to avoid all JavaFX API entirely (why?) in the model, then you can use a different observer/observable implementation (your own if you like), but that is the standard way to do this. No idea why you think this design has anything to do with causing null pointer exceptions.

Comment: w.r.t "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-#"  assuming you are not aware of Platform.runLater() https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html

Comment: Maybe I should have made clear that this is my first JavaFX application and I might be unaware of some best-practices... :(

Comment: Also Platform.runLater(runnable) causes the whole JavaFX thread to sleep on Thread.sleep(500) inside the runnable Object `runnable`; thereby freezing the whole application while waiting.

Comment: You misunderstood that. Use `Platform.runLater(...)` to *update the UI*, not to invoke `Thread.sleep()`. Polling like this is definitely not a recommended implementation though. Use a "notification" style approach, as in MVC instead. Why don't you post some code, so someone can actually answer your question, instead of everyone debating in the comments section.

Comment: Thanks for the code: however, please post code as ([properly formatted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)) text, not as a screen shot of your IDE. That way anyone who wants to copy and paste the code (to test it or to use it in a solution) can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your log (model) like this:

```
public class ShopLog {

    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper logText = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty textProperty() {
        return logText.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }
    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    // Implement as many methods like this as your API needs:
    public void log(String logMessage) {
        logText.set(logText.get() + "\n" + logMessage);
    }
}
```

Clearly this class has no knowledge of the view (or the view's controllers/presenters), so does not violate the separation of view and model.

Your controller can look like this:

```
public class ShopLogController {

    private ShopLog log ;

    @FXML
    private TextArea logDisplay ;

    public void setShopLog(ShopLog log) {
        logDisplay.textProperty().bind(log.textProperty());
    }
}
```

So now when the `log(...)` method is called on the `ShopLog`, the text area in the view is automatically notified (via the binding), and will update the text displayed. The binding is managed from the controller, not the model, which preserves the appropriate separation of concerns. There is no need at all for any polling (with its arbitrary polling intervals and threading to manage).

As an aside, this is not a particularly scalable solution, because you are storing the data as one monolithic string and updating via string concatenation, with the display using a text area. I showed this implementation as it seems to be the one you are using (based on your comments and the screenshot). You might consider using other general implementations, such as the model using an `ObservableList<String> logMessages` instead.

Comment: This is the kind of solution I was looking for, thank you so much!

Because I have basically the same problem around a List, you also solved my issue there. :)